# Adding foursmallest elements from alist using php

Tags: php

i want to add the aggregates of best five performed subjects from alist of 10 subjects

```
$scores=(1,2,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,7)
```

The scores of student are as above

I want to `sum five small elements` from list  `$agg ie(1,1,2,2,3)`
and my answer should be `9 in best five`

Comment: Try $first_five = array_slice(asort($fscores), 0, 4); You first sort by value, then get items from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* fist sort the fist five small numbers using following script */

$scores=array(1,2,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,7);  // array list
$sum_five_small_elements = 0;

sort($scores);


for($x = 0; $x < 5 ; $x++) {
    /* now sum all five small elements */
    $sum_five_small_elements += $scores[$x];   
}

echo $sum_five_small_elements;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) along with the [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) as

```
$scores = array(1,2,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,7);
sort($scores);
print_r(array_sum(array_slice($scores, 0,5)));//9
```

Here Firstly I have sorted the values using [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) which'll sort an array from `lowest to highest` as

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 )
```

Afterwards I have sliced an array into two using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) which'll result into

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 )
```

And finally using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) it'll sum out the array which results into

```
9
```

Comment: Glad to help.(_FYI: You can accept or upvote an answer which solves or help to solve your problem._)